# Increase brightness in Laptop using console mode

Tags: command-line, 18.04, asus, brightness, battery

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus laptop with NVIDIA graphics and an Intel i5 CPU. ASUS ROG G531GD

I accidentally decreased my screen brightness to 0 in the battery settings before I could configure the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys (they do not work by default).

So I restarted and shifted to console mode when the login screen appears by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and after logging I insert the following command

```
xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " "
```

results in

> Can't open display

I also tried to blindly type in terminal the following:
`xrandr --output "$(xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " ")" --brightness 1`. nothing changed

How do I use the console mode to change my brightness level considering that [xrandr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xrandr.1.html) wont work.

I can log into recovery mode.

Comment: Have you tried bypassing the NVIDIA driver (whichever version you have, you didn't provide the NVIDIA graphics adapter model or driver number) by interrupting GRUB and temporarily adding _nomodeset_ to the line which chooses Linux? See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 . If that does not help, remove the NVIDIA drivers to force reversion to nouveau at the next boot with _nvidia-installer --uninstall && sudo apt remove nvidia-*_

Comment: I feel that I can modify the battery settings instead. Is there a way to modify the battery settings stored in some txt/conf file?

Comment: Can I get my FN keys to work at least?

Comment: After logging in, the screen cuts to black. I cant even go to console mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xrandr` does not work because there is no X session at the console. Hopefully changing `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` value will restore the brightness immediately. You should try

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness'
```

If you already have the necessary privileges (e.g. already root),

```
echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

suffices.

Comment: THanks I blind-typed it into the terminal and it worked

Comment: That was in the console. In fact, I could only open the console when I was asked to login with my password. After loggin in I could not open the console

Comment: So I used the Ctrl+Alt+T to open the terminal and slowly blindtyped the whole sequence

Comment: I had a similar problem with a Dell XPS 13 display. The brightness values appear to range not from `0` to `100`, but from `0` to `7500`. The following worked for me:
`sudo su`, `echo 7500 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, `exit`.